# Canvas inside viewpager receives touch event when user swipes

Tags: android, canvas, ontouchlistener

I have a canvas in which I am drawing a horizontal line as seen below. I draw this line based on user touch events , and I move the line along y axix only. This canvas is inside viewpager. When I try to swipe to next page canvas detects the touch event and changes the position of line . So how can I differentiate between when user wants to change the position of line or user wants to swipe to next page. I have tried experiments with touch event of pager and canvas , and the fragment that contain canvas , nothing worked as I required. Any help , suggestions appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Show some code man, your screenshot provides nothing

Comment: @QBM5 , thanks for replying , I  dont have any bugs in my code , just wanted to know how to prevent canvas get touch event when user intend to swipe the viewpager , , still if you want , I will post the code  , and the links I have referred.

Comment: @Sumit Have you found solution?

Comment: @Olexii , I have tried many different things without luck ,I guess using custom viewpager is the only solution.